# Detecting the number of horizontal and vertical lines in an image to predict any symbol

Tags: java, image, image-processing, count, marvin-framework

I'm trying to get the detect the number of horizontal and vertical lines and based on that, I want to detect the name of the symbol.

I have tried this approach,
[Java image analysis - counting vertical lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932618/java-image-analysis-counting-vertical-lines)
but the solution is very image specific whereas in my case, the image threshold would change according to the image.

[image]

[image]

These are some of the symbols that I have to detect (have a set of more 30 symbols). I have used some other approaches using Marvin, but those are also not giving me proper results.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You could train a neural network to perform a simple task like this.

Comment: Yes. I did. In fact, it took around 50 hrs to train the model but still, there was no output. So my professor asked to find a simpler alternative approach.

Comment: A blob detection algorithm could probably tell you how many unconnected shapes are in the image, where they are located, and what their dimensions are. From there, just checking if the width is longer than the height would tell you if the shape is horizontal or vertical. Though if you have actual connected shapes that might be a bit difficult. The second image here might still work, though, if you exclude all fades. But the top of the top one would be one line, not two. You'd need more analysis to separate those.